# How to bind a textBlock text to some string property at run time

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a textBlock

`<TextBlock Width="180" Text="{Binding Details,  UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"`

and in the viewModel

```
public string Details
    {
        get
        {
            string strInfo;      
            strInfo = Resources.SharedOn+": " + DateString;

            strInfo += "\n"+Resources.Access+": " + AccessString;

            if (ExpiryString != Resources.ShareExpireNever)
            {
                strInfo += "\n" + Resources.ShareExpire + ": " + ExpiryString;
            }
            if (Note != null && Note != "")
            {
                strInfo += "\n"+Resources.ShareNote+": " + Note;
            }
            return strInfo;
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(DetailsProperty, value);
        }
    }
```

I want to bind this property in such a way that whenever user make any changes in the UI, this `TextBlock` this three values immediately reflect the values. I have added

`UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged`

but this is not working. 
Any ideas why it's not working?

Comment: Seems like something is wrong here ... Why does your `ViewModel` contains `Details` as a dependency property?

Comment: just put the code you have written into get to set part..s

Comment: Is Details a Dependancy property? Also, you have binded it to TextBlock, how are you changing it from UI????

Comment: The property I have defied in the "info.cs" class and in the Project

Answer (score 0):

If your other properties are dependency properties, then you should set [PropertyMetadata](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms557328.aspx) in their declarations. There you can specify property changed callback, where you can update `Details` property by calling its setter.

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty NoteProperty = 
    DependencyProperty.Register("Note", typeof (string), 
    typeof (YourObject), new PropertyMetadata(String.Empty, UpdateDetails));

    private static void UpdateDetails(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var o = (YourObject)d;
        o.UpdateDetails();
    }

    private void UpdateDetails()
    {
        string strInfo;
        strInfo = Resources.SharedOn + ": " + DateString;

        strInfo += "\n" + Resources.Access + ": " + AccessString;

        if (ExpiryString != Resources.ShareExpireNever)
        {
            strInfo += "\n" + Resources.ShareExpire + ": " + ExpiryString;
        }
        if (Note != null && Note != "")
        {
            strInfo += "\n" + Resources.ShareNote + ": " + Note;
        }
        Details = strInfo;
    }
```

If your other properties are not dependency properties, then you can simply call `UpdateDetails` from their setters.

Either way, you should not modify getters and setters of dependency properties. Meaning, they should look like:

```
    public string Details
    {
        get { return (string) GetValue(DetailsProperty); }
        set { SetValue(DetailsProperty, value); }
    }
```

without any custom code.

Comment: Yes other properties also dependencies Properties. AccessString, DateString, ExpiryString, Note all are dependency properties.  I didn't get your UpdateDetails() code

Comment: @Debhere, what dont you get exactly? It is your code. I copy-pasted it from your getter.

Answer (score 0):

the main problem i see is that your trying to use a DP as a value converter

Instead of doing a concatination in the details property use a multibinding to do it in the GUI, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.multibinding.aspx

this will then allow you to set the value converter to both convert and reverse the data